# How do you make your submit login button take you to your php page?

Tags: php, html, forms, button

This is what I am currently doing:

```
<form method="get" go="welcome.php">
    <button type="submit">continue</button>
</form>
```

But it is just taking me to an error page that says:
Firefox can't find the file at /action_page.php?

Check the file name for capitalization and other typing errors,
Check to see if the file was moved, renamed or deleted.

I even did rename it and I put in my form and it still doesn't go to my php page! Anyone know how to do it better.

Still I am only a starter at code and barely know what I'm doing.

Comment: `go` isn't a valid (form) `action`. There's also no "php" here.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the `action` attribute.

```
<form method="get" action="welcome.php">
    <button type="submit">continue</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. What if it says that /action.php thing? What do I do? Still, thanks Jon!